# Allow only access from specific URL to whole website

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have this code on domain-1.com in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://domain-2.com/$
RewriteRule https://domain-1.com/ - [F,NC]
```

My goal is that only users from domain-2.com can come to domain-1.com by clicking the link.

`<a href="http://domain-1.com">link to domain-1.com</a>`

Blocking page domain-1.com works perfectly but access from domain-2.com does not work.

Comment: I assume you understand that such protection is not secure in any form, since it is trivial to forge the referrer header in requests. If that is fine for you then the code should work if that header contains _exactly_ what you expect. Is that the case? How did you check? I wonder for example if you really want `/$` at the end of your matching pattern ...

Comment: Removing /$ does not help. Still getting error: Access Forbidden

Comment: So what is actually set as referrer header in those requests?

Comment: RewriteRule matches against the path component of the URL only.

Comment: @CBroe LOL, sorry, I was so focussed on the condition, I completely missed that point. I wonder though why the OP then claims that blocking works ... Must be some other effect blocking all requests which again explains why the condition does not work ...